# JWT with Angular and SpringBoot

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, jwt

I want to integrate a JWT authentication in my current Angular application which is connected to a spring boot backend.

I looked through quiet a lot of tutorials, but most of them did not fit, since they were connected to Auth0. I want to handle the usermanagement by myself.

I found this example:

Angular: https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/angular-springboot-jwt-integration-p-1-800a337a4e0

Spring Boot: https://medium.com/@nydiarra/secure-a-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-reference-to-angular-integration-e57a25806c50

Unfortunately, this Angular Frontend is Angular 4 and I'm using Angular 6 already. They use the 'angular2-jwt' which is not compatible with Angular 6. I have to use 'auth0/angular-jwt'.

My problem is, that after I use my login form, the browser opens again a login popup to login the backend. But even with the right credentials, it doesn't work. I'm guessing, that some credentials are missing in the request. In the app.module.ts are 2 old angular2-jwt code, which i don't know how to upgrade it to auth0/angular-jwt

```
export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    headerPrefix: 'Bearer',
    tokenName: TOKEN_NAME,
    globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}],
    noJwtError: false,
    noTokenScheme: true,
    tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_NAME))
  }), http);
}
```

and

```
providers: [
    {provide: AuthHttp, useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory, deps: [Http]},
]
```

Can someone help me with this issue. May be I'm wrong with my guessing and it could be something else?

A side note; I just changed my frontend but trying to connect to the backend from the example. If I'm using both front- and backend from the example, its working fine.

Comment: jhipster is a really good example of how to do JWT with spring boot.

Comment: @Peter - If you resolved your issues, is it possible to post your code. I am now migrating to auth0/angular-jwt and having lot of issues. If you want I can share my code in github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have passed successful migration from angular2-jwt to auth0/angular-jwt several months ago. What you have to keep in mind while doing so is:

- auth0/angular-jwt uses new angular HttpClient library, so if you want to use so, you have to migrate all your application to it (I suggest doing so anyway, new library is quite amazing)
- new angular-jwt uses HttpInterceptors - this allows you to attach JWT directly to HttpClient filters chain. So you don't have to migrate your code above. You have to remove it completely and replace with interceptor initialization: (copy-paste from auth0/angular-jwt documentation):

  ```
  import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
  import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

  export function tokenGetter() {
    return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  }

  @NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
      // ...
      HttpClientModule,
      JwtModule.forRoot({
        config: {  
          tokenGetter: tokenGetter,  
          whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:3001'],  
          blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:3001/auth/']  
        }  
      })  
    ]  
  })  
  export class AppModule {}
  ```

Remember to apply this code in your root module - then use your HttpClient without any changes and interceptors will apply JWT automatically. In case of problems - blame whitelistedDomains/blacklistedRoutes. These fields are very poorly implemented at the moment and are causing problems with regular expressions etc. 
As migration is not straightforward, and took me a lot of time, feel free to ask about it. There's high probability, that I'll know the answers.

Comment: Thank you very much Michal. Your info helped me alot, though it wasnt the issue in my code. But this you could not know. You directed me into the right way.
My problem was, that the headers were not send, since the synthax from angular 6 changed. I could not just append headers to the header object, i had to use .set(). now it is working and i just need to implement the backend from the example into my spring boot backend

Comment: @Michal - I am now implementing auth0/angular-jwt. Not sure why it never authenticates if the user has actually logge dor not. I mean when I click on User lick, earlier it used to go to login page if the user has not authenticated. but now it directly goes to user page. Can you please help me. If there is complete code in gihub, can you please share the same.

Comment: @Michal - If you want I can share my code in github

Comment: @Michal - I am able to login, but for next rest call (GET request), it does not authorize. I guess it does pass the token. How to pass the token?